# StereoBm Opencv function gives an error "object of an abstract class cannot be defined"

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, syntax-error, disparity-mapping

When I intialise StereoBM object I get an error "object of an abstract class cannot be defined". I checked calib3d.hpp and I found that StereoBM is an abstract class. Please provide me a solution how to define all those functions in StereoBM class

```
cv::Mat leftimg =cv::imread("leftimage.jpg");
cv::Mat rightimg = cv::imread("rightimage.jpg");
cv::Size imagesize = leftimg.size();

cv::Mat g1,g2,disp,disp8;
cv::cvtColor(leftimg,g1,cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::cvtColor(rightimg,g2,cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

cv::StereoBM *sbm;    
sbm->setDisp12MaxDiff(1);
sbm->setSpeckleRange(8);
sbm->setSpeckleWindowSize(0);
sbm->setUniquenessRatio(0);
sbm->setTextureThreshold(507);
sbm->setMinDisparity(-39);
sbm->setPreFilterCap(61);
sbm->setPreFilterSize(5);
sbm->compute(g1,g2,disp);
normalize(disp, disp8, 0, 255, CV_MINMAX, CV_8U);

cv::imshow("left", leftimg);
cv::imshow("right", rightimg);
cv::imshow("disp", disp8);
```

Comment: opencv version ? (also the pointers in like: `sbm.state->preFilterSize = 5;` look suspiciously wrong

Comment: opencv version 3.0 and I have edited to include the correct code ,I wrote wrong code initially. Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Ptr<StereoBM> sbm = createStereoBM(16,2); // else it will be dead before you can use it. (you *need* the smartpointer here)

Comment: Thanks a lot , your suggestion fixed my problem..:)I'm really thankful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion in the comment fixed the error so I'm posting the working code after replacing it with the suggestion so it can help others in case of similar problem.

```
cv::Mat leftimg =cv::imread("leftimage.jpg");
cv::Mat rightimg = cv::imread("rightimage.jpg");
cv::Size imagesize = leftimg.size();
cv::Mat g1,g2,disp,disp8;
cv::cvtColor(leftimg,g1,cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::cvtColor(rightimg,g2,cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

cv::StereoBM *sbm=cv::createStereoBM(16,2);    
sbm->setDisp12MaxDiff(1);
sbm->setSpeckleRange(8);
sbm->setSpeckleWindowSize(0);
sbm->setUniquenessRatio(0);
sbm->setTextureThreshold(507);
sbm->setMinDisparity(-39);
sbm->setPreFilterCap(61);
sbm->setPreFilterSize(5);
sbm->compute(g1,g2,disp);
normalize(disp, disp8, 0, 255, CV_MINMAX, CV_8U);

cv::imshow("left", leftimg);
cv::imshow("right", rightimg);
cv::imshow("disp", disp8);
```

Comment: do you remember which opencv version you tried this sample code? in `3.3.1`, I get this error for compilation: `error: ‘createStereoBM’ was not declared in this scope
   StereoBM *sbm= createStereoBM(16,2);`

Comment: For 3.3.1 try  StereoBM *sbm = StereoBM::create(16, 2); , this should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using version 3.1, you will get the following error:

```
use of undeclared identifier 'createStereoBM'
```

For 3.1 you can try:

```
StereoBM *sbm = StereoBM::create(16, 2);
```